# How to pass a list of coordinates to the default google Map Application?

Tags: android, google-maps

From my app i am opening the default google map app. Here is how i am doing it.

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f(%s)",
                locationList.get(1).getLatitude(), locationList.get(1).getLongitude(),"My location");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        Log.i(TAG, "Uri is "+ uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);
```

This is working fine. But is it possible to pass a list of coordinates and plot them all so i could create a path?

Comment: you want to draw a path from one destination to other on google maps??

Comment: I want to draw the path between multiple coordinates that are stored in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this:

```
String destination = locationList.get(1).getLatitude()+","
                    +locationList.get(1).getLongitude();
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+destination+"&mode=d");
            Log.e(TAG,"Intent uri : "+gmmIntentUri.toString());
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            this.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

this will open map in navigation mode from your current location to the specified destination.

you can have a look at the below link to specify way points between your source and destination:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple coordinates though? I've asked about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47690024/878126